# git lost changes when merging back and forth between two branches

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have two branches, let's call them 'development' and 'stable'. Most of the time I merge from development to stable but sometimes I need to merge in the opposite direction. For example, somebody changes a script or config file and I want to get these changes into my development branch.

Most of the time merging works fine but on a couple of occasions I noticed that git attempts to revert my recent changes in development branch to an older version coming from stable branch. Why would this happen? I talked to our resident git guru and he says that merging back and forth is the likely reason but he couldn't explain how exactly it happens.

For example, I do a merge from stable to development with --no-commit. I am looking at a file and it has a recent change in development branch and an older change in both development and stable. But git still insists on reversing the newer change for some reason.

Comment: I see no reason that merging from one branch to another and then back should cause this behavior. In fact, such a procedure is relatively common, and I haven't had it cause any issues before. Have there ever been any merge conflicts when this happens? Can you provide a [mcve]? Please try to at least narrow it down a little bit, and then post relevant `git log` and `git diff` output (properly sanitized, of course).

Comment: `git merge --no-commit --no-ff stable development; git merge --abort` gives `Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested`?

Answer (score 0):

Besically in order to avoid whole problem all together, while on `development` branch run

`git rebase stable`

What it will do is take the commit stack of your `development` branch and reply them ***ON TOP*** of `stable` branch. This way you will get an up to date `development` branch and avoid unecessary `merge` commits.